# Space at the end of AlertDialog.Builder

Tags: android, android-layout

I am unable to remove the space at the end of my dialog, I have looked if I was adding some padding at the end, but I am before did not have that problem, but then I added an element that began to occur.

Print

[image]

This is the xml I'm using for my view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="23dp"
    android:background="#5454C3">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:background="#FF33CC">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp" >

            <br.lgfelicio.elementos.TextViewChanged
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#9B9B9B"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:text="DESTINO" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:id="@+id/editTextFiltroRegiao">

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spnEstadoFretes"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="-14dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#C0C1C0"
        android:layout_marginTop="-15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:visibility="visible"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:background="#00FF00">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp" >

            <br.lgfelicio.elementos.TextViewChanged
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#9B9B9B"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:text="COMPLEMENTO" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:id="@+id/editTextFiltroComplemento">

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spnComplemento"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="-14dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#C0C1C0"
        android:layout_marginTop="-15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:visibility="visible"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:background="#FF0000">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp" >

            <br.lgfelicio.elementos.TextViewChanged
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#9B9B9B"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:text="PREÇO" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:id="@+id/editTextFiltroPreco">

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spnPreco"
                android:layout_marginTop="-14dp"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#C0C1C0"
        android:layout_marginTop="-15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:background="#000000">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <br.lgfelicio.elementos.TextViewChanged
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/progresTexto"
                android:textColor="#9B9B9B"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:text="RAIO" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <SeekBar
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:id="@+id/raioSeekBar"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you post the xml for this layout?

Comment: Updated the image, I want to remove the padding / space you have in the bottom.

Comment: Have you tried with <Space../> element view?

Comment: Space require API 14 and I'm working from 10